# App recommendations for a new Ubuntu user

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm a new Ubuntu user. I need some help with the applications i should have on ubuntu.

Apps for :

- File Download
- Torrents
- Video and audio players

and any other apps that can be useful

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Your question is too broad. Such discussion would fit a forum format but this is a Q&A. Besides that, the standard Ubuntu already has pretty much everything you need by default. You may need to install *ubuntu-restricted-extras* for additional codecs and you may want to install additional software like VLC or KODI Media Center if you prefer those but, again, it's optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of those applications should allready be installed.

File Download:
Not sure what exactly you mean, other than a browser like firefox.
For bigger files I use the console and wget.

Torrents:
I recommend Transmission

Video:
MPlayer

Audio:
VLC Player

Other:
The console is the most useful tool, because you do pretty much anything with it. It lacks usability in some cases, but apt-get is very useful for quick installation, you should take a look at that on any ubuntu wiki. LibreOffice, Eclipse (for programming), Evince (PDF Reader), VirtualBox, Thunderbird (Email) are other typical applications I use.

Comment: I like VLC for *both* audio and video.